# Cartotype and Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing an offline routing app in a team with Cartotype.
We’ve implemented the MapView successfully, and it is working when we test it on a real Android device.

But when i use the Genymotion Emu for testing it, the activity is crashing when called with the following error message in the log cat.

```
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at de.hshn.tourwest.classes.CMapView.init(CMapView.java:109)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at de.hshn.tourwest.classes.CMapView.onDraw(CMapView.java:245)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1144)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2147)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cartotype: findLibrary returned null
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     at com.cartotype.Framework.<clinit>(Framework.java:944)
05-25 16:37:19.468: E/AndroidRuntime(1050):     ... 42 more
```

i have no android device around me, so that i need to use an emulator.

The libs are correct added:

```
<project>\libs\cartotype.jar
  <project>\libs\armeabi\libcartotype.so
```

Comment: Please contact me via the CartoType enquiries form or e-mail address on the web site; we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion runs on x86 architecture.

When the `loadLibrary` method is executed, the Runtime will try to find the library (.so) inside the folder `app_data/libs/x86/`

To run your app on this emulator Cartotype needs to support it. 
When a library supports x86, the libs directory should look like:

```
<project>\libs\myLib.jar
  <project>\libs\armeabi\myLib.so
  <project>\libs\x86\myLib.so
```

It seems Cartotype does not support x86. So, you should ask to Cartotype to support this architecture as a growing number of devices are using x86 CPUs, including Genymotion.

Or you can try to find another offline maps library that supports x86.

Comment: CartoType's Android SDK now includes both ARM and x86 builds.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Genymotion, use the standard Android emulator in the SDK.  Because that emulates an ARM CPU, rather than trying to run x86 code directly, it should cope with your library only being provided in ARM form.

Yes, I know this will be slower, but slower is better than not working at all in this case.